# ERROR: calling procedure. No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inserir_funcionario(
    funcionarios_nome VARCHAR(50),
    sexo_nome CHAR(1),
    data_admissao TIMESTAMP,
    matricula VARCHAR(10),
    setores_nome VARCHAR(50),
    cargos_nome VARCHAR(50),
    cargos_salario DECIMAL(10,2),
    in_telefones VARCHAR(30)[][],
    enderecos_cep VARCHAR(9),
    enderecos_estado VARCHAR(50),
    enderecos_cidade VARCHAR(50),
    enderecos_bairro VARCHAR(50),
    enderecos_rua VARCHAR(50),
    enderecos_numero VARCHAR(6),
    enderecos_complemento VARCHAR(50),
    acessos_usuario VARCHAR(20),
    acessos_senha VARCHAR(100)
)

LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
fk_cargos RECORD;
fk_setores RECORD;
fk_funcionarios RECORD;
telef VARCHAR(30)[]; 
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '1';
    EXECUTE "SELECT id_setores FROM setores WHERE nome = 'Produção'" INTO fk_setores;
    EXECUTE "SELECT id_cargos FROM cargos WHERE nome = 'Operador'" INTO fk_cargos;
RAISE NOTICE '2';
    INSERT INTO funcionarios(nome,sexo,data_admissao,matricula,fk_setores,fk_cargos)
    VALUES (funcionarios_nome,setores_nome,current_timestamp,matricula,fk_setores,fk_cargos);

RAISE NOTICE '3';
    EXECUTE "SELECT id_funcionarios FROM funcionarios WHERE matricula = 'matricula'" INTO fk_funcionarios;

RAISE NOTICE '4';
    INSERT INTO acessos(usuario, senha, fk_funcionarios)
    VALUES(acessos_usuario, acessos_senha, id_funcionarios);

RAISE NOTICE '5';
    INSERT INTO enderecos(cep,estado,cidade,bairro,rua,numero,complemento,fk_funcionarios)
    VALUES(enderecos_cep,enderecos_estado,enderecos_cidade,enderecos_bairro,enderecos_rua,enderecos_numero,enderecos_complemento,fk_funcionarios);
RAISE NOTICE '6';

    FOREACH telef SLICE 1 IN ARRAY in_telefones
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO telefones(tipo,numero,fk_funcionarios)
        VALUES(telef[1],telef[2],fk_funcionarios);
    END LOOP;

END;
$$;
```

When i try o get a call. it gets an error.

```
CALL inserir_funcionario('Andre','M',current_timestamp,'A123','Produção','Operador',1000.00,ARRAY[['cel','26516564'],['con','54132165']],'12345678','SP','São Paulo','Vila Mariana','Rua dos Bobos','0','Casa','andre','123456');
```

```
ERROR:  procedure inserir_funcionario(unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown, unknown, unknown, numeric, text[], unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: CALL inserir_funcionario('Andre','M',current_timestamp,'A123...
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What client are you using to `CALL` the procedure?

Comment: The procedure code is invalid to begin with. String constants must be enclosed in single quotes. You can't have dynamic SQL using double quotes (and the dynamic SQL is useless anyway)